# LVDS vs driver strength in FPGA IO

Tags: current, fpga, lvds, io

In the FPGA, there is I/O constraints that can be done to configure the output buffer. Some of these constraints are like setting the output drive strength parameter, on die termination, output delay, and IO standard.
If I chose my IO standard to be **LVDS33** and the output drive is set to be 6mA, what is the meaning of this output drive when LVDS standard is chosen?

I understand that the output current in LVDS assuming we follow the standard LVDS is approximately 3.5mA to maintain 350mV drop across the 100 ohms resistor, so does that mean when LVDS is chosen the IO drive strength if set higher than 3.5mA is only used to compensate for any losses in transmission to maintain the standard LVDS differential voltage, so on the transmission line end I would see 3.5mA?

Using MPF300T-1FCG484I microchip FPGA:

[image]

Comment: Which FPGA manufacturer and part are you referring to, your question doesn't say? Please edit new info into the question, don't add it in comments.

Comment: What does it say in the Microchip documentation for the part/tools?

Comment: It says the same options found when editing the IO constraints (2mA/4mA/6mA) but my question is more about the LVDS concept, that is if the drive strength is 6mA wouldn't that mean the 100 ohms resistor would have a 600mV drop ? Or is this drive strength not relevant when LVDS is chosen and the current is always approximately 3.5mA.

Answer (score 1):

The LVDS specification specifies a drive current of 3.5 mA minimum.  It does not specify a maximum drive current, except that which could be inferred from driver output voltage specifications and receiver input voltage requirements, with a given termination scheme.

So yes, a 6 mA drive current and a 100 ohm parallel termination resistor would provide a voltage swing of +/- 600 mV, which is still acceptable and within the range specified by the LVDS specification document.

My opinion only - the higher drive current capability may be to accommodate interfaces where the differential Zo, and so the parallel termination resistor, may be less than 100 ohms.